# Entity Framework: non-existant columns are added to query on a many-to-many relation table

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I've stumbled upon a strange issue in EF. I have the following class hierarchy in my EF model

```
public abstract class Entity
{
   [Column]
   public string Id { get; set; }

   [Association("Links", "Id", "SourceId", IsForeignKey = false)]
   public List<EntityRelation> Relations { get; set; }
}

public class A : Entity
{
}

public class B : Entity
{
}

public class EntityRelation 
{
  [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
  [Key]
  public long Id { get; set; }

  [Column]
  public int SourceId { get; set; }

  [Column]
  public int TargetId { get; set; }

  [Column]
  public RelationType RelationType { get; set; }
}
```

Where A and B are concrete classes mapped to tables, and the `EntityRelation` class is mapped to a table that contains logical relations between rows in either table of A and B.

The strange issue occurs when I try to insert rows into the `Links` table - the EF generated `INSERT` statement looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO Links (SourceId, TargetId, RelationType, **A_Id**, **B_Id**)
VALUES (...)
```

For some reason, EF generated an `INSERT` statement which is concat'ed with A_Id, B_Id columns for every derived type.

Of course the `INSERT` command fails with the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'A_Id'. Invalid column name 'B_Id'

How do I avoid this?

Comment: `A and B are concrete classes mapped to tables` - do you have table for entity in db, or only tables for these classes? Also you didn't `Relations` to `Entity` where it's target. do you use fluent api?

Comment: @ingvar I have table per entity in DB. I didn't use fluent API to define the relation, but through the Association attribute.

Comment: I mean, is there a table for `Entity` type or you have tables per concrete types only?

Comment: @ingvar per concrete type. Not for the base entity.